# Connection refused: In connecting Google cloud postgresql with Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect google cloud sql instance with cloud function written in python.

```
global pg_pool, pg_pool_db_name
pg_config = {
    'user': CONNECTION_DATA[dbname]['DB_USER'],
    'password': CONNECTION_DATA[dbname]['DB_PASSWORD'],
    'host': host,
    'dbname': dbname
}

pg_pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(1, 1, **pg_config)
```

This function test call failed and it outputs error message:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/my_instance_name/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Anybody experienced on this kind of situation.

Comment: Hi, you don't specify which runtime are you using or which documentation are you following to perform the connection. I can sugest you to follow the official [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions)

Comment: I am using python3.7 runtime. And on the document I am not sure with this part, "sure the service account used has the correct permissions"

Comment: Can you share how did you deploy your Cloud Function?

Comment: I deployed the python function to source repository.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tutorial about [Connect from google cloud functions to Cloud SQL](https://github.com/mvladoi/GCS-python/blob/master/Connect%20from%20google%20cloud%20functions%20to%20Cloud%20SQL)

```
9.Create a service account for your cloud function. Ensure that the service account for your service has the following IAM roles: Cloud SQL Client, and for connecting from Cloud Functions to Cloud Sql on internal ip we need also the role Compute Network User.

    gcloud iam service-accounts create cloud-function-to-sql
    gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding gcf-to-sql --member serviceAccount:cloud-function-to-sql@gcf-to-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com   --role roles/cloudsql.client
    gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding gcf-to-sql --member serviceAccount:cloud-function-to-sql@gcf-to-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com  --role roles/compute.networkUser
```

Then deploy the function using the service account you just created:

```
2.Deploy the cloud function:

    gcloud beta functions deploy gcf_to_sql --runtime python37 --region europe-west2 --service-account cloud-function-to-sql  --trigger-http
```

## EDIT

Please read this documentation:

1.[Creating a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-create-console)

2.[Granting roles to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts)

3.[Deploying  Cloud function from Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/console)

> Click More to display advanced options, such as setting a region,
> specifying a timeout, or adding environment variables

On Advanced options, choose the service account you just created.

Comment: Would you mind to explain me how to archive this goal with google cloud console?